# Can't remove title element when tooltip is displaying

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm adding a `title` to a `div` with a simple line of:

```
j$("#div").attr("title", "My title.");
```

Inside the `div` is a selector box. When you select something in the selector box, it then calls code to remove the `title` of the `div`. (This is using the `.change` function, if it matters.)

```
j$("#div").removeAttr("title");
```

This code works great if the current title tooltip is not displayed. However, if the title tooltip is being displayed, the jQuery can not remove the `title` from the `div`. Because the selector is inside the `div`, mousing over the selector displays the `title`. Going down and selecting an item in the selector keeps the tooltip displayed the entire time. Even if I force-close the tooltip, the `removeAttr` code still can't remove the `title`, because the code executes faster than the tooltip's fadeout.

I either need a way to successfully stop the animation (I've tried using variants on stop, and can just never seem to actually get the tooltip correctly to run stop on it), a way to delay the code that removes the title until the fadeout is finished (I tried `settimeout`, whic didn't work), or a way to force remove the title even though the tooltip is still open.

Comment: You mean [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/)?

Comment: I've specifically tried .stop(). I have not tried .finish().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said how you are creating the tooltips, which matters.

If you are using jQueryUI's tooltips feature (and if not, why not?), then you must use `tooltip('destroy')` to unbind the tooltips, thus:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXRe5/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div">
    <select id="divSel">
        <option value="0">Choose One:</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Add Title" />
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$(document).tooltip();

$('#divSel').change(function() {
    $(document).tooltip( "destroy" );
    $("#div").removeAttr("title");
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $("#div").attr("title", "This is a title added to display a tooltip.");
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**css:**

```
#div {width:20%;height:80px;background:wheat;margin-bottom:10px;}
#divSel{margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;}
```

Comment: I'm not using jQueryUI's tooltis feature because they're not really needed. All I need is to add a title on a div under certain conditions, and to remove it under other conditions. That's all.

I did try explicitly using your suggested method. It still won't remove the title attribute if the tooltip is displayed.

Comment: Okay, then something else is going on. See [this revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXRe5/2/) -- all jQueryUI tooltip code has been removed. Note that the `title` attr removes just fine when `select` is changed.  (*Use Chrome Dev Tools - F12 in Chrome - to watch in real time as the title is added to the DIV, then removed when select is changed.*)

Comment: Edited. Yes, the revised fiddle works now. Interesting. So even though I'm not explicitly using jQueryUI code, it's still likely the cause. I know the library is there. I'll have to work around that.

Thanks. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fadeOut() or something similar. The function callback is executed when the fade out is complete.

```
$( "#div" ).click(function() {
  $( "#div" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not dynamically showing/hiding a div s a popup. What you have there would hide the div my selector is in. It would work great if I knew how to find the actual popup tooltip that occurs on div over.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to say what might be wrong, but I am unable to recreate this issue.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzh6b/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div" title="My title.">
<div>#div</div>
<select id="sel">
    <option value="0">Add tooltip</option>
    <option value="1">Remove tooltip</option>
    <option value="">Do Nothing</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>Log:</div>
<div id="logger"></div>
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
var $log = $('#logger');
function log(text){
    $log.append($('<div></div>').html(text));
}
$('#sel').change(function(){
    switch(parseInt($(this).val())){
        case 0:
            $('#div').attr("title", "My title.");
            log('Added tooltip');
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#div').removeAttr("title");
            log('Removed tooltip');
            break;
        default:
            log('Nothing happened');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#div{height:200px;width:200px;background:#FFFFF0;border:1px solid red;}
```